# Prove partial derivatives exist, but not all directional derivatives exists.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

During my analysis course my teacher explained the difference between partial derivatives and directional derivatives using the notion that a partial derivatives looks at the function as approaching a point along the axes (in case of of the plane), and a directional derivative as approaching a point from any direction in the plane. He also explained that the existence of directional derivatives is a stronger notion than the existence of partial derivatives exists: if all directional derivatives exist, then the partial derivatives exist too.

I am to show (not necessarily prove) a case where the partial derivatives exist, but not all directional derivatives exist (hence, f is not differentiable).

Comment: note that even if all directional derivatives exists, $f$ need not to be differentiable :-)

Comment: Thank you. I'm meant to show this in a later exercise too. For now I only want to show an example I think. I can't come up with a function, however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider for instance
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}&\text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0),\\
0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
The partial derivatives exist everywhere. Away from the origin this is clear. At the origin we need to calculate the partials from first principles:
$$\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}h=\frac{0-0}h=0$$
so letting $h\to0$ we find $f_x(0,0)=0$. By symmetry we also have $f_y(0,0)=0$. However, not all directional derivatives exist at the origin. For example, let $\mathbf v=(\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$. Then
$$\frac{f(\mathbf0+t\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf0)}{t}=\frac{\frac{t^2}{t^2+t^2}-0}t=\frac1{2t}$$
which does not have a limit as $t\to0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you happen to know a systematic way of finding such a function with this property, or is it usually found as an educated guess?

Comment: Usually functions of the form $f(x,y)=\frac{x^jy^k}{(x^2+y^2)^n}$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ are good for these kinds of questions. Tweak the exponents depending on whether you're looking at continuity or differentiability.