# Differentiability of $f$ in $\mathbb{R^m}$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is true that if $A\subset \mathbb{R^m},$ $f:A\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $D_jf$ (partial derivatives) exist in and are bounded in  a neighborhood of $a\in A$ then $f$ is differentiable?

I think this is true but I don't see how to use the fact that there exist $M>0$ such that $|D_jf|<M$ for each j. Also, I know if I can show that $D_j f$ is continuous at $a,$ the result follows from that.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Not sure this is true. With the given hypothesis, that $f$ is *continuous*  can be proved, but *differentiable*, I am not sure.

Comment: астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  Oh, I see... And how would I prove that f is continuous?

Comment: The answer below gives a counterexample. The hint would be to use the mean value theorem (for one dimension, using the partial derivatives), and the chain of expressions that is used, to show that if $D_jf$ are continuous then $f$ is differentiable (i.e. where you split  a difference component by component). If you are unaware, you may request an answer.

Comment: indeed, you need the partials to be continuously differentiable to get total differentiable. Ask about partial differentiable to continuity in another question. I'll need to give that a thought. but my hunch is that's also a no.

Answer (score 1):

[This counter example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1749837/133152) disproves the statement. (Note: Total derivative exist is equivalent as all directional derivatives exist.)